Inconsistent parsing of Excel headers in pandas dataframe
Consider the following table in Excel:
                    h1  h1_1    h1_2    h1_3
                    h2  h2_1    h2_2    h2_3
                    h3  h3_1    h3_2    h3_3
                                
                    h4  h4_1    h4_2    h4_3
                    h5  h5_1    h5_2    h5_2
i1  i2      i3      h6  h6_1    h6_2    h6_2
    i1_2    i1_3    foo         
    i2_2    i2_3    foo         
    i3_2    i3_3    foo                 1

This table has 7 header rows, and 4 index columns. Moreover, the indices and headers have names, and header name h6 overlaps with what would be index name i4.
I parse this with pandas as follows:
import pandas as pd
df_scratch = pd.read_excel('scratch2.xlsx', index_col=[0,1,2,3], header=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])

However, then it seems that the first row is skipped:
df_scratch
            h1  h1_1    h1_2    h1_3
            h2  h2_1    h2_2    h2_3
            h3  h3_1    h3_2    h3_3
                Unnamed: 4_level_3  Unnamed: 5_level_3  Unnamed: 6_level_3
            h4  h4_1    h4_2    h4_3
            h5  h5_1    h5_2    h5_2
            h6  h6_1    h6_2    h6_2
    i2_1    i3_1    foo             
NaN     i2_2    i3_2    foo     NaN     NaN     NaN
i2_3    i3_3    foo     NaN     NaN     1.0

To confirm, df_scratch.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'i1_2',:]] returns KeyError: 'i1_2', while df_scratch.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,'i2_2',:]] returns:
        h1  h1_1    h1_2    h1_3
        h2  h2_1    h2_2    h2_3
        h3  h3_1    h3_2    h3_3
            Unnamed: 4_level_3  Unnamed: 5_level_3  Unnamed: 6_level_3
        h4  h4_1    h4_2    h4_3
        h5  h5_1    h5_2    h5_2
        h6  h6_1    h6_2    h6_2
    i1_3    foo             
NaN     i2_3    foo     NaN     NaN     NaN

If I parse with one header row less, then the last header row is interpreted as data:
import pandas as pd
df_scratch = pd.read_excel('scratch2.xlsx', index_col=[0,1,2,3], header=[0,1,2,3,4,5])

            h1  h1_1    h1_2    h1_3
            h2  h2_1    h2_2    h2_3
            h3  h3_1    h3_2    h3_3
                Unnamed: 4_level_3  Unnamed: 5_level_3  Unnamed: 6_level_3
            h4  h4_1    h4_2    h4_3
            h5  h5_1    h5_2    h5_2
i1  i2  i3  h6  h6_1    h6_2    h6_2
i1_2    i1_3    foo     NaN     NaN     NaN
i2_2    i2_3    foo     NaN     NaN     NaN
i3_2    i3_3    foo     NaN     NaN     1

Is it possible to read the correct lay-out outright, or do I need to first read the Excel file without any headers/indices, and add them after having read them?
